# How to generate instance of trait for another trait

Tags: rust, traits

TL;DR: What's the accepted way to `impl` a trait for all types implementing another trait in Rust?

I'm working through trying to understand Rust's type system and coming to a bit of a hangup. I've boiled the problem down, and realized that I'm basically just trying to translate the following thing I can write in Haskell to Rust:

```hs
class Wrapper s where
  unwrap :: s t -> t

data Burrito t = Burrito t

instance Wrapper Burrito where
  unwrap (Burrito inner) = inner

instance (Wrapper w, Show t) => Show (w t) where
  show w = "(wrapped " ++ show (unwrap w) ++ ")"


main :: IO ()
main = 
  print . Burrito $ 1
```

I was able to generally translate this as follows:

```rust
trait Wrapper<T> {
  fn unwrap(&self) -> T;
}

struct Burrito<T> { filling: T }

impl<T: Copy> Wrapper<T> for Burrito<T> {
  fn unwrap(&self) -> T { self.filling }
}

impl<T: Display, W: Wrapper<T>> Display for W {
  fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
    write!(f, "(wrapped {})", self.unwrap())
  }
}

fn main() {
  let burrito = Burrito { filling: 1 };
  println!("{}", burrito);
}
```

But this errors on the `T` type parameter in the Display `impl` with error:

> the type parameter `T` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
> unconstrained type parameter

The other alternative I tried was doing (as suggested by my IDE):

```rust
impl<T: Display> Display for dyn Wrapper<T> {
  fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
    write!(f, "(wrapped {})", self.unwrap())
  }
}
```

but this now raises an error on the actual println in main (when done as `println!("{}", burrito as Wrapper<i32>)`), that there is a cast to an unsized type.

Is there a canonical way to create an `impl` for a trait (`Display` here) for all types `impl`ementing another trait (`Wrapper<T>` here)?

Comment: Keeping the alternative `impl` you can do `println!("{}", &burrito as &dyn Wrapper<_>);` (note the `&`s), avoiding casting to an unsized type. Rust makes this hard to do because you might want to impl `Display` for `Burrito<T>` at some point which would conflict with the impl for `Wrapper`.

Comment: `impl<T: Display, W: Wrapper<T>> Display for W` would conflict with a normal `impl Display` for type `W`, if it already existed or was added later on. That kind of thing would also allow you to implement an external trait for an external type, just by going through a trait you own.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @isaactfa that seems to work for me - if you write it up as an answer, i'll happily accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @PitaJ - kind of mostly playing around with Rust to see what's possible & what isn't within the type system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
impl<T: Display> Display for dyn Wrapper<T> {
  fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
    write!(f, "(wrapped {})", self.unwrap())
  }
}
```

implements the `Display` trait for a `dyn Wrapper<T>` [trait object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/trait-object.html#trait-objects). This is a type of object in Rust which uses dynamic dispatch instead of monomorphization. Because trait objects are dynamically sized, you can't store them on the stack. You can, however, keep a reference of type `&dyn Wrapper<T>`:

```
fn main() {
    let burrito = Burrito { filling: 1 };
    println!("{}", &burrito as &dyn Wrapper<_>);
}
```

This is obviously a little more complicated than one would expect but there's a good reason. If you could `impl<T: Display, W: Wrapper<T>> for W` you couldn't `impl Display for Burrito<T>` anymore as that would conflict with the other impl and vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

As the error says, the type parameter `T` is not constrained enough. Rust wants that at least one of the following conditions to be met to use a generic type `T` in an impl block:

- it must be used as a parameter (or as a parameter of a parameter, or ...) of the implementing type;
- if you are implementing a trait, it's ok if it's a parameter of the trait;
- it's bound as an associated type of the implementing type.

It's the last option that fits your need:

```rust
trait Wrapper {
    type Output;
    fn unwrap(&self) -> Self::Output;
}

struct Burrito<T> { filling: T }

impl<T: Copy> Wrapper for Burrito<T> {
    type Output = T;
    fn unwrap(&self) -> T { self.filling }
}

impl<T: Display, W: Wrapper<Output=T>> Display for W {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> Result {
        write!(f, "(wrapped {})", self.unwrap())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let burrito = Burrito { filling: 1 };
    println!("{}", burrito);
}
```

See the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b29a58483c2b2069d2ec723f56f222dc).

---

As note by @isaactfa, this will not compile, but for a different reason. You cannot implement a foreign trait `Display` for any type `W`, no matter the constraints on `W`. This is called the orphan rule.

Comment: The Playground doesn't compile.